# 'OS X-like' momentum scrolling in linux?

Tags: x11, touchpad, user-interface

Is there a way to make the scrolling on a linux machine (running X11) more like OS X's natural scrolling? With 'natural scrolling' I mean the fact that you can flick trough the pages, there is momentum in the scrolling.

I have a macbook running Arch Linux and I would like to make the trackpad experience a bit better.

Comment: what are you looking for is probably defined as "kinetic scrolling", i suggest a research on the internet about your distribution specific solutions, because this can involve 3 pieces of software, drivers, desktop environment and possible third part software.

Comment: Have you tried GNOME 3's ["natural scrolling"](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-system-settings.html.en)?

Comment: I accidentally discovered that [this Firefox Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yet-another-smooth-scrolling/) has option for making "bouncy" feedback when reaching the page top/bottom edge. Works with Firefox 40 on Linux.

Comment: Try `man synaptics` (not `man synaptic`) and read the configuration manual for the touchpad driver used for touchpads on lots of (but not all) hardware. Search for the word "coasting". EDIT: Just realized how old this post was. :-/

Answer (score 2):

In plasma5 (kde5) this is called Coasting and it can be conveniently configured via  Configure Desktop (systemsettings5) | Input Devices | Touchpad | Scrolling (Tab).

You can set there how fast you have to do your scrolling for the Coasting to set in (scrolls/second) and how strongly the scrolling momentum decelerates after you've lifted your fingers (scrolls/second²).

Comment: Is there a similar feature for Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easy with synclient:

```
$ synclient VertScrollDelta=-70
$ synclient HorizScrollDelta=-70
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is called *Coasting*:

```
$ synclient -l | grep Coasting
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
```

Adjust the `CoastingSpeed` and `CoastingFriction` to set how fast it scrolls and how soon it stops scrolling.